# LinkedIn API OAuth issue

Tags: python, oauth, linkedin-api

This is my first time using the LinkedIn API. I am using Python.
I am exactly following the steps listed here: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-oauth-token-python

Everything goes well until I try to get the PIN for the access token. I type into my browser: `"https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=" + oauth_token` , and then I get the error "`We were unable to find the authorization token.`"

I also tried to download the full code linked at the top of the page, but that goes to a "`page not found`".

Anyone have any insight as to why I can't get the access token PIN? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize for not seeing this sooner.  The code on that page has been restored and you can download it now without issue.

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-oauth-token-python

If it's still not working, please let us know (I'll check back here, or you can post in our forums).  I use essentially that exact code whenever I test our API so it should work.